# How to use the Reader Monad when traversing an Abstract Syntax Tree

Tags: haskell, monads, abstract-syntax-tree

I have an abstract syntax tree in haskell made from Parsec. I want to be able to query its structure while traversing it at the same time in order to translate it into intermediate code. For example, I need to know how many parameters any given function of my AST takes in order to make this translation. What I am currently doing is passing in the AST to every single function so I can call it whenever I need to do a lookup and I have helper functions in another file to do the lookups for me. This is polluting my type signatures. Especially when I begin to add more things like an accumulator.

Instead of passing in the AST to every function I've heard this would be a good job for the Reader Monad (for state that doesn't change, the AST) and the State Monad (for state that does change, the accumulator).

How can I take the ast out of the IO monad (*gulp*) and use it in a Reader Monad to do global lookups?

```
main = do
  putStrLn "Please enter the name of your jack file (i.e. Main)"
  fileName <- getLine
  file <- readFile (fileName++".jack")
  let ast = parseString file
  writeFile (fileName++".xml") (toClass ast) --I need to query this globally
  putStrLn $  "Completed Parsing, " ++ fileName ++ ".vm created..."

type VM = String

toClass :: Jack -> VM
toClass c = case c of
   (Class ident decs) ->
     toDecs decs 

toDecs ::[Declaration] -> VM -- I don't want to add the ast in every function arg...
toDecs [] = ""
toDecs (x:xs) = case x of
  (SubDec keyword typ subname params subbody) ->
    case keyword of
      "constructor" -> --use the above ast to query the # of local variables here...
    toSubBody subbody ++
    toDecs xs
  otherwise -> []
```

UPDATE on Reader Monad progress:
I have transformed the above example into something like this: (see below). But now I'm wondering due to all this accumulation of string output, should I use a writer Monad as well? And if so, how should I go about composing the two? Should ReaderT encapsulate writer? or vice versa? Should I make a type that just accepts a Reader and a Writer without attempting to compose them as a Monad Transformer?

```
main = do
  putStrLn "Please enter the name of your jack file (i.e. Main)"
  fileName <- getLine
  file <- readFile (fileName++".jack")
  writeFile (fileName++".xml")  (runReader toClass $ parseString file)
  putStrLn $  "Completed Parsing, " ++ fileName ++ ".xml created..."

toClass = do   
  env <- ask
  case env of Class ident decs -> return $ toDecs decs env

toDecs [] = return ""
toDecs ((SubDec keyword typ subname params subbody):xs) = do
  env <- ask
  res <- (case keyword of
            "method" -> do return "push this 0\n"
            "constructor" -> do return "pop pointer 0\nMemory.alloc 1\n"
            otherwise -> do return "")
  return $ res ++ toSubBody subbody env ++ toDecs xs env
toDecs (_:xs) = do
  decs <- ask
  return $ toDecs xs decs

toSubBody (SubBodyStatement states) = do
    return $ toStatement states
toSubBody (SubBody _ states) = do
    return $ toStatement states
```

http://hpaste.org/83595 --for declarations

Comment: You have found a very appropriate opportunity to use the reader monad. Indeed, you don't want to pass around the AST all the time. However, in your sample code, I can't see any (and I expected multiple) functions taking in a AST. Maybe you can paste code with less details of your domain?

Comment: Tarrasch, one example would be the "constructor" case. Its result needs to be: "push pointer " ++ (show $ getFieldCount subname ast) ++ "\n" I have it outlined in the code above.

Comment: in `toDecs` you bind `res`, but never use it. I'm not sure if thats a mistake or a typo. Also, what is the type of `toDecs`? In the first 2 cases it takes 1 input, but in the 3rd it takes 2.

It would be much easier to help if you provided a code fragment that compiles (ie. with the data definitions for `Class`, `SubDec`, `SubBody` etc...)

Comment: Chris, you are exactly right. I forgot to add res to the return expression. I've added an hpaste of all my declarations. http://hpaste.org/83595

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing a bit more about the `Jack` and `Declaration` types it's hard to see how to transform it into a Reader monad. If the idea is to perform a "map" or a "fold" over something while having the `ast :: Jack` object in scope, you might write

```
f :: [Declaration] -> Reader Jack [Something]
f decls = mapM go decls where 
  go :: Declaration -> Reader Jack Something
  go (SubDec keyword typ subname params subbody) =
    case keyword of
      "constructor" -> do
        ast <- ask
        return (doSomething subbody ast)
```

and then execute it in context with your `ast` as `runReader (f decls) ast`.

Comment: thank you for your code, its been most helpful. The Jack declaration is a large AST. Basically a lots of nested lists. [Declaration] is just one level of that AST. Another question though. How would I go about using the Writer monad as well in the "constructor" -> do portion. I want to pass the AST and keep a [[String]] which will accumulate as I traverse the AST downward.

Comment: Just in case. data Jack = Class Identifier [Declaration] deriving (Show); 

data Declaration = ClassVarDec Keyword Type [VarName] |
                   SubDec Keyword Type SubName [Params] SubBody
                   deriving (Show)

Comment: Well, there's a big variation as to what you do if `VarName` or `Params` contains another `Jack`. In either case, you'll want to look into monad transformers and see how to build a `WriterT [[String]] (Reader Jack)` monad so that you can both `ask` and `tell`. The packages you'll want to look at are `transformers` and `mtl`, both are quite standard. `transformers` is a little more verbose, `mtl` takes advantage of typeclasses to be a bit less verbose.